# Saving images locally yet unreadable

Tags: c#

I have a program in c# that downloads images from a web service.
The download usually takes time so I want to save the images locally so I would only need to download each image once. The problem with that is when the images saves the user of the program can see the image in the files and change it.
Is there a way to save the image in the program, yet keep it from users to see and change in the folder?

EDIT: solution used: 
 Encrypting the images and their names when I save them, and only access them this way. (decrypting when after reading them).

Comment: Not really, but you could XOR encrypt to make it beyond the reach of the naive user.  `CryptProtectData` would be another option.  You could also just hash the image and re-download if the hash doesn't match the server hash.

Comment: I thought about your idea @Mitch of encrypting the files before I save them and then decrypt them later. Thought there would be a more "elegant" solution but I guess I'll use that.

Comment: "Elegant" is in the eye of the beholder, encryption is quite elegant IMO and will solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

What is your intent?  Anything your program has access to do, your user does as well.  If you're just trying to prevent people from accidentally mucking with your images, then save off a SHA1 or similar hash of the file and store it separately.  When you need an image, check the SHA1 and redownload if it doesn't match.  This will prevent casual tampering, but still isn't 100% effective against malicious changes.

Comment: I have a game in windows forms where you play as a ball, you can change that image by purchasing skins in the game, those skins are saved locally, but as a player you can enter to the folder and just change the image to whatever skin you'd like. That's what I'm trying to prevent. The idea of using SHA1 is pretty good to prevent changes, but I don't want users to see the images from the file explorer as well.

Comment: You could also sign your images with your SNK and then check the signature for the images with your assemblies public key.  if they don't match then someone screwed with your images.  (and it wouldn't require a server call to confirm they are playing with the files.)

Comment: Matthew Whited has the right idea.  You can actually embed your images as a resource in a DLL that's strong signed and Windows will refuse to load it if it's been tampered with.  (Unless they turn off strong signing)

Comment: The problem with embedded files is that they are static to the program, while in reality new images could be uploaded by permitted users on the server.